# AJAX PARA LLAMAR METODO EN EL BACKEND, ALGUIEN CON IDEA DE CUAL PUEDA SER EL ERROR

Tags: html, c#, ajax

Quiero llamar a un método en el back end desde ajax, este método debe llevar dos datos que son números pero los puedo mandar como string también.

Este es mi código de ajax, funciona el alert pero nunca entra al metodo, lo se por que tengo un breakpoint:

```
int x = (Number(e.target.parentElement.children[1].textContent));
 int xy = (Number(e.target.parentElement.children[0].textContent));

$.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "MillsData.aspx/EliminarSeleccionado",
                      //data: '{semana2: "' + x.value + '" }',
                      data: JSON.stringify('{semana2: "' + x.value + '" }'),
                      dataType: "text",
                      success: function (response) {
                          alert("SI SIRVE LO DEL AJAX");
                          
                      },
                      failure: function (response) {
                          alert(response.d);
                      }
                  });
```

Y este es el método en el backend que es c# En este método tengo un breakpoint para saber cuando entre pero nunca llega a esa parte del código.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static void EliminarSeleccionado(int semana2)
        {

            //objcon.SQL_Eliminar_Datos("2021",Convert.ToString(semana2));
            int x = semana2;
        }
```

Comment: En el browser, cuando vas a la pestaña network qué respuesta obtienes? 400's, 500's?

Comment: Cómo dice @Arriel, debes revisar con F12 según el navegador la pestaña de "Network o Red" y revisar la invocación de EliminarSeleccionado para determinar que status tiene la llamada y el response exacto

Answer (score 0):

Mi ajax quedo asi

```
 $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "MillsData.aspx/EliminarSeleccionado",
                          data: JSON.stringify({ "semana": x, "anio": xy }),
                          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                          dataType: "json",
                          success: function (response) {

                          },
                          error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
                              alert(errorthrown);
                              alert(textstatus);
                          }
                      });
                      confirm("Se ha eliminado el dato seleccionado.");
                      location.reload();
```

Y en el metodo del aspx.cs solo e hacia falta cambiarlo a static

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static void EliminarSeleccionado(string semana, string anio)
        {
            SQL_Connection objcon = new SQL_Connection();
            objcon.SQL_Eliminar_Datos(anio,semana);
            
        }
```

Con esto logre hacerlo funcionar.